# Set Object Reference in UFT with or without the "Execute" Statement

Tags: vbscript, qtp, hp-uft

Recently I have been assigned a project wherein the object references are set using the "Execute" Statements as shown below:

```
Execute "Set objButton = XamRibbonWindowAddin(""XamWindow_DashBoard"").WpfButton(""Save"")"
```

Whereas, my approach for setting the object references has always been like this(without the "Execute" Statement):

```
Set objButton = XamRibbonWindowAddin("XamWindow_DashBoard").WpfButton("Save")
```

I have been using the latter method as it allows me to make use of Intellisense in UFT which is quite an advantage sometimes.

Is there any reason I need to switch to the 1st approach or Should I ask How is one approach better than the other? I could not get much from the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the `Execute`d code is pre-defined and doesn't contain any parts that are determined dynamically by the test I don't see any benefit of using `Execute`.

An example of *dynamic* code may be something like this contrived example which determines what the variable is called according to some previously computed value `theType`.

```
Execute "Set obj" & theType & " = XamRibbonWindowAddin(""XamWindow_DashBoard"").Wpf" & theType & "(""Save"")"
```

Then if `theType` is *Button* it will define the variable `objButton` and if it's *Edit* it will define `objEdit`.

As I said this is a contrived example, I've never ran across anything that would require you to use `Execute` in UFT.

Since you're entering into an existing code base, consistency has it's values. If possible I would ask one of your more experienced co-workers what motivated them to use this construct to better form an opinion.

Comment: Thanks for your Inputs, Motti. Would it be possible for you to share an example wherein the code inside the Execute statement has some dynamic part in which case I would be more inclined towards setting the object reference using the Execute statement?