# How to Store All Text in Between Two Index Positions of Same String in VBScript?

Tags: asp.net, string, vbscript

So I am going off memory here because I cannot see the code I am trying to figure this out for at the moment, but I am working with some old VB Script code where there is a data connection that is set like this:

```
set objCommand = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.command")
```

and I have a field from the database that is being stored in a variable like this:

```
Items = RsData(“Item”).
```

This specific field in the database is a long string of 
text:

(i.e. *“This is part of a string of text…Header One: Here is text after header one… Header Two:  Here is more text after header two”*).

There are certain parts of the text that I wish to store as a variable that are between two index positions in the long string of text within that field.  They are separated by headers that are stored in the text field above like this:  “Header One:” and “Header Two:”, and I want to capture all text that occurs in between those two headers of text and store them into their own variable (i.e. *“Here is text after header one…”*).

How do I achieve this?  I have tried to use the InStr method to set the index but from how I understand how this works it will only count the beginning of where a specific part of the string occurs.  Am I wrong in my thinking of this? Since that is the case, I am also having trouble getting the Mid function to work.  Can some one please show me an example of how this is supposed to work? Remember, I am only going off of memory so please forgive me that I am unable to provide better code examples now.  I hope my question makes sense!

I am hopeful that someone can help me with an answer tonight so I can try this out tomorrow when I am near the code again!  Thank you for your efforts and any help offered!

Comment: Did you give it a try?

Comment: @Gurman Yeah I did I appreciate your help.  It got me close to solving the issue at hand.  I am going to try to get more work done with it and post some follow up info before I mark this as correct, but I probably will be doing so soon!  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can extract all the substrings starting with the text `Header` and ending just before either the next `Header` or end-of-string. I have used regular expression to implement that and it is working for me. Have a look at the code below. If I get a simpler(non-regex solution), I will update the answer.

**Code:**

```
strTest = "Header One: Some random text Header Two: Some more text Header One: Some random textwerwerwefvxcf234234 Header Three: Some more t2345fsdfext Header Four: Some randsdfsdf3w42343om text Header Five: Some more text 123213"
set objReg = new Regexp

objReg.Global = true
objReg.IgnoreCase = false
objReg.pattern = "Header[^:]+:([\s\S]*?)(?=Header|$)"      '<---Regex Pattern. Explained later.
set objMatches = objReg.Execute(strTest)
Dim arrHeaderValues()                         '<-----This array contains all the required values
i=-1
for each objMatch in objMatches
    i = i+1
    Redim Preserve arrHeaderValues(i)
    arrHeaderValues(i) = objMatch.subMatches.item(0)      '<---item(0) indicates the 1st group of each match
next

'Displaying the array values
for i=0 to ubound(arrHeaderValues)
    msgbox arrHeaderValues(i)
next
set objReg = Nothing
```

**Regex Explanation:**

- `Header` - matches `Header` literally
- `[^:]+:` - matches 1+ occurrences of any character that is not a `:`. This is then followed by matching a `:`. So far, keeping the above 2 points in mind, we have matched strings like `Header One:`, `Header Two:`, `Header blabla123:` etc. Now, whatever comes after this match is relevant to us. So we will capture that inside a Group as shown in the next breakup.
- `([\s\S]*?)(?=Header|$)` - matches and captures everything(including newlines) until either the next `Header` or the end-of-the-string(represented by `$`)

  - `([\s\S]*?)` - matches 0+ occurrences of any character and capture the whole match in Group 1
  - `(?=Header|$)` - match and capture the above thing until another instance of the string `Header` or end of the string

[Click for Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xoT2O0/1)

**Alternative Solution(non-regex):**

```
strTest = "Header One: Some random text Header Two: Some more text Header One: Some random textwerwerwefvxcf234234 Header Three: Some more t2345fsdfext Header Four: Some randsdfsdf3w42343om text Header Five: Some more text 123213"
arrTemp = split(strTest,"Header")         'Split using the text Header
j=-1
Dim arrHeaderValues()
for i=0 to ubound(arrTemp)                 
    strTemp = arrTemp(i)
    intTemp = instr(1,strTemp,":")        'Find the position of : in each array value
    if(intTemp>0) then
        j = j+1
        Redim preserve arrHeaderValues(j)
        arrHeaderValues(j) = mid(strTemp,intTemp+1)      'Store the desired value in array
    end if
next

'Displaying the array values
for i=0 to ubound(arrHeaderValues)
    msgbox arrHeaderValues(i)
next
```

If you don't want to store the values in an array, you can use Execute statement to create variables with different names during run-time and store the values in them. See [this](https://ss64.com/vb/execute.html) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44156333/5331061) for reference.

Comment: That did work for me. I modified code to use a dictionary array and store the header name so I could call each stored value by referencing that instead of index. Thanks for your help I appreciate it! Sorry it took me so long to accept this as the answer I have just been a busy coder!